# AWS logs tail --follow until it find the phrase

Tags: github-actions, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I would like to prepare a Github Action workflow which will print live logs from my deployed application using aws logs CLI but also stop following/printing logs after it find a defined phrase. I was trying to use awk but with no results. Any suggestion how to achive this?

I've tried to use awk but with no results. Script doesn't stop printing logs

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833, it looks like the problem in this case lies in pipe buffering. For details, read the different answers on the linked question - looks like there may be different buffering types involved here.

Specific to tailing CloudWatch Logs, a possible solution might look like this for Mac/FreeBSD:

```bash
script -q /dev/null aws logs tail /aws/ssm/my-run-document --follow \
  | sed '/Stop on this line/ q'
```

... and on Linux systems it would be:

```bash
script -q -c 'aws logs tail /aws/ssm/my-run-document --follow' /dev/null \
  | sed '/Stop on this line/ q'
```

**EDIT:** turned out that for some reason the `script` command expects an ENTER at the end. The solution I've come up with to mitigate that is to use named pipes and background processes:

```
mkfifo fifo
echo | script -q fifo aws logs tail /aws/ssm/my-run-document --follow &
sed '/Run Finished/ q' <fifo
rm fifo
```